# How to ask complicated questions in acceptable manner, especially in the c++ tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, asking-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

I think this is happening repetitively to me. Sometimes I ask a question that asks how to do:

- Something that is not actually supported by the API I use, but is not explicitly stated anywhere
- Something about outdated compilers, libraries that I cannot replace but need to solve the problem

Of course, this is not intentional, I ask because I don't know the problem cannot be solved or is much much more complicated than I thought. Even if I include all resources I have, such as code sample, relevant links to documentation I have read, errors, ideone MCVE, even after all that, downvotes are guaranteed.

I will now narrow this post to my last question, which turned out as a missing feature in compiler. It is not clear though, whether it's missing or broken and whether there's any workaround:

- [Cannot convert from 'const std::initializer_list<_Elem>' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty>' where both templates are int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38742810/607407)

In the question, I have included:

- Full error report
- All relevant code that can be easily pasted and tested (and people claim to successfully do so)
- Ideone sample of the code, which clearly compiles under the new compiler
- Info about what compiler I'm using
- Info about what I tried to do with the code to fix this

I received two downvotes out of 8 visits. Also, someone posted close vote:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

I received zero comments asking for improvement of anything specific in the post.

After spending 20 minutes to assemble question about that's enough to make me angry. The close vote specifically seems like someone was incompetent to read/understand the question.

Is my post as valid as I think it is? If it's not why? Othervise, how can I prevent people from downvoting a valid post?

Note that this is not standalone case, but it's significant because after previous experience, I tried to post in even higher quality. Also, older posts like this eventually attract upvotes from people who google them and are trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119018/discussion-on-question-by-tomas-zato-how-to-ask-complicated-questions-in-accepta).

Comment: What is "Ideone sample"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Runnable code that can be viewed and compiled on ideone.com. It's basically JSFiddle for other languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's talk about where that downvote likely came from.

It didn't come from someone downvoting your post because it was "hard" or "unanswerable". It likely came because you didn't do any research.

For example, if you had looked around on your own, you would have found that Visual Studio 2010 did not support most of C++11, including initializer lists. That kind of information is an easy Google search away. Yet it never occurred to you that a compiler released *before C++11 was standardized* might have incomplete support for said standard.

I probably wouldn't downvote a question for that reason, but I can certainly understand the impulse to do so.

It should also be noted that, in general, the C++ tag community has higher standards than the average SO community. They will downvote time-wasting questions liberally. As far as I'm concerned, that's a *good thing*.

Comment: I was confused about this because the compiler actually supports lot of the features, such as lambda functions or the `auto` identifier. Since it includes the headers for initializer lists, I would expect them to work, why else they would be there? To date, nobody explicitly posted an answer that the compiler does not support initializer lists at all. So it's not as clear in my opinion.

Comment: @TomášZato: "*the compiler actually supports lot of the features*" No, it doesn't. [This is a table of C++11 features supported by VS versions.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#featurelist) See how many "No"s are in the 2010 column? Yes, Microsoft supported a couple of highly useful bits of C++11 in VS2010. But "lots" is absolutely untrue.

Comment: Sorry, I underestimated the amoung of features C++11 has, so the few seemed like lots to me. I stand corrected and thanks for the table.

Answer (score 3):

> Is my post as valid as I think it is? If it's not why?

You're asking for an objective answer to a subjective question. This question and votes on it are subjective, so there is no correct answer here.

> Othervise, how can I prevent people from downvoting a valid post?

Stack Exchange does not offer such a feature, and with good reason. Think of the abuse that would ensue.

> Please try to work under assumption that I'm really posting here because I honestly want to ensure I ask questions like this in an acceptable manner.

I would start by taking the feedback you've received thus far seriously, rather than deny the validity of it.

Comment: I am not aware of any feedback except for not using `C++` tag if possible, which I too seriously. I am not asking for objective answer (if you wanna play philosopher, eventually you reach conclusion such thing does not exist), I am asking for answer backed by explanation. I don't even know if this answer is meant seriously or is just some kind of Meta humor.

Comment: @Tomas Improving/creating an MCVE has been suggested numerous times, but still you argue it unnecessary.

Comment: Not true, I improved further already quite clear MCVE. Where did I said it is unnecessary? And why would I improve it if I thought so? It is quite impolite to accuse someone of saying something just out of the blank. After numerous (in number 2) people suggested MCVE isn't clear enough, my reply was: "*I deleted some code to make it literally copy&paste job. Technically only thing that was necessary to delete was inheritance...*" My reply was not that it is not necessary, so why do you lie exactly?

Comment: @Tomas You literally just commented to defend your statement that whoever voted to close for lack of clear problem/MCVE was "incompetent". But whatever, deny that too...

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Why did you suddenly change topic to talk about completely different comment in different thread? Why should I refute or explain anything if you're clearly going to ignore any explanation and instead come with something new to complain about?

Comment: \*resists urge to copy-paste newest bizarre comment in reply\*

Comment: That's fine, you don't seem to do a good job copying anything relevant so far.